# Ubuntu Linux UFW Firewall, Local Intranet Access

Tags: server, networking, firewall, intranet

At home, I have Ubuntu server with the UFW firewall. What command do I type to turn on local intranet access to my web server, but keep the outside world out from my DSL modem?

Comment: Is the DSL modem a NATing router?  If so, and if you haven't forwarded any ports to the server, then leaving the firewall wide open is fine--nothing's getting past the router.

Comment: This is a just-in-case kind of thing. You never know when some thief finds a router exploit and can play with MAC addresses to get through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sudo ufw default deny
sudo ufw allow from 192.168.1.0/24 to any port 80
```

Assuming the web server is on port 80 and 192.168.1.x is your home subnet. If you explicitly want exclude your router, then assuming it's 192.168.1.1, it would be:

```
sudo ufw deny from 192.168.1.1 to any port 80
```